# Dynamically add control disappear after postback

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, postback

I have an aspx page with the following code:

```
 <asp:Table ID="JsonContent" runat="server">
     </asp:Table>
```

In my behind code at `Page_Load` i add Items to Table.

Table consist two rows:

Row num 0 is Cell that contain `TextBox`

Row num 1 is Cell that Contain `TextBox`

Additionally i have a button `save`, when the user click the button i need to go over all table row and write the data at `Text Prop` to File.

The problem is that when i click the `Button Save` the event page_load raise and all `text box` control is not already exist so i can no write the edited data to file.

I read about similar post with this issue, but could not get a solution.

Thank!

Comment: You should (re-)create all dynamically added controls in `Page_Init` in every postback because all objects are disposed when html is sent to the client. But even if you recreate them there they will persist the user-input if you assign the same ID as before.

Comment: Can you update the question with your page load code?

Comment: @TimSchmelter I try your solution, after i create the textBox with same ID, How i add it again to asp .NET page?
The Problem is all control are null , i.e my panel that contain the dynamic textBox

Comment: You'll have to show us more code, mainly your html part and the page load, because if you have controls inside other controls it can be more complex

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you should learn about asp.net pages web cycle : https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178472.aspx

And i would say that @TimSchmelter has the perfect solution for you in the comments :

"You should (re-)create all dynamically added controls in Page_Init in every postback because all objects are disposed when html is sent to the client. But even if you recreate them there they will persist the user-input if you assign the same ID as before"

This means you have to use the function page_init (wich is similar to page_load but not automaticly generated, you have to write it manualy)

I did this once too, and I confime that Tim's solution will work.

Just make sure that your page_init() fucntion is reached.

Comment: can you have  a look at my question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55817451/pre-init-function-not-finding-all-dynamic-controls . i am having the same issue

Comment: @KeshavTaurah I will take a look at it once I have more time on my hand.